# Opentest Backspace issue

Tags: selenium, opentest

I have done the below steps:

1. I have entered promoCode `test`
2. Clear the promo Code
3. Enter another promoCode `abc`

I have problems with Step 2, I tried to use `SendKeys` with Backpace `\u0008` or `Keys.BACKSPACE` but did not work.

> description: Type "backspace" in the search box
> action: org.getopentest.selenium.SendKeys
> args:
> locator: { id: promoCode }
> text: "\u0008"
> sendEnter: true

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `clearContent` argument, which will clear the text box before typing in the new text:

```
- description: Type new text in the search box
  action: org.getopentest.selenium.SendKeys
  args:
    locator: { id: promoCode }
    clearContent: true
    text: <NEW TEXT HERE>
```